# How to use caret package in r to tune the detailed structure of neural network

Tags: r, neural-network, r-caret

I am new to ANN, and I am struggling on how to tune my ANN. My question is how can I determine the ANN structure (like how many hidden layers and nodes in each layer) is the best, or at least good enough to use. I heard that package caret can be utilized to determine the best structure. I have gone through the package manual, but cannot figure out how it works. So can anyone give me the basic ideas about this issue, or some hints, or some useful links, so that I can go ahead to check. It's not limited to caret package, other efficient and useful packages are also OK, or some other ways to set up the ANN. Your help is very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For finer control on ANN, probably you should try Keras. https://keras.rstudio.com/

Comment: yifyan, thank you for your suggestion. I think I have used Keras before. I can specify how many layer are there as well as the nodes in each layer. But it was difficult to determine the overall structure, and the activation function in each layer, and the solver are hard to choose as well. Trial and error is not a good method to use. Again, I am new to ANN, I may be wrong about what I write here. Can you give me some general ideas about how to control the structure, or please send some links that you think are helpful if you have any. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I you want to understand how you should control the structure, then you should try asking questions in Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/ . Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: OK I see. Thanks

Comment: try [tfruns](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tools/tfruns/articles/overview.html) with keras.